# Return same select if exists

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, exists

Having a query like:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE Property=1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE Property=1
    END
else
    begin
        SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE Property= (SELECT Property FROM [OtherTable] where OtherProperty = 1)
    end
```

Is it possible to modify it in order to not do the same select twice?

Comment: That depends, what is the second `SELECT`'s `WHERE`? Though with the right indexes something like the above can be more performant.

Comment: @Larnu It is a subselect from other table, I've added the details to the question

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, then you can use "Select top 1 1 From" instead of "Select * From" in Exists statement.

Comment: @AntonGrig At least in MS SQL Server, using `TOP` in an `EXISTS` query makes no difference. And there is no difference between using `SELECT 1` and `SELECT *` in an `EXISTS` query either.

Comment: @Richard Deeming It really is. Thanks for the remark, now I have filled in this gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Merge Concatenation to do this. Just join the two queries with `UNION ALL`, add an ordering column to `ORDER BY`, then `SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES`

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES`
  *
FROM (
    SELECT *, 1 AS Ordering
    FROM [MyTable] t
    WHERE Property = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *, 2
    FROM [MyTable]
    WHERE Property = (
        SELECT Property
        FROM [OtherTable]
        where OtherProperty = 1)
) t
ORDER BY Ordering;
```

If `Property` in the second query is guaranteed to be `>= 1` then you can just do it all in one and `ORDER BY Property`

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES`
  *
FROM [MyTable] t
WHERE Property IN (
 1,
 (
     SELECT Property
     FROM [OtherTable]
     where OtherProperty = 1
  )
ORDER BY Property;
```

I suggest you have an index on `Property` with relevant `INCLUDE`s to support this query

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @Property INT= 1;
DECLARE @LocalProperty INT;
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM [MyTable]
    WHERE Property = @Property
)
    BEGIN
        SET @LocalProperty = @Property;
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @LocalProperty = Property
        FROM [OtherTable]
        WHERE OtherProperty = @Property;
    END;
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE Property = @LocalProperty;
```